# SSH port has been blocked by Iptables on my VPS. Can I enable it?

Tags: iptables

The port 2222 has been blocked by Iptables on my VPS.

And I set SSH to use port 2222.

So now I can not login my VPS though SSH.

Sorry,I forget to give VPS distribution I am using.

It is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64 bit.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please read an iptables howto (like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo -- you want section 5 in this one) and update your question if you need more specific assistance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are locked out of your VPS you will now have to use whatever tools your VPS host provides for emergency recovery to disable iptables. As you don't mention which distribution you are using we can't help with that.

To open port 2222 will need to add something like the line below to your iptables configuration file.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```